# Using ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, field-calculator, modelbuilder, python-parser

I am trying to create a ModelBuilder model to calculate factor of safety for shapefiles. However, whenever I try to run the python my 'Slope' comes up as undefined and I have no clue what to do.

Here is my expression fields:

```
factorofsafety (!soil_depth!, !cohesion!, !soil_dens!, !hydro_cons!, !frict_ang!, !Slope!)
```

This is my code block:

```
def factorofsafety (soil_depth, cohesion, soil_dens, hydro_cons, frict_ang, Coweeta_slope):
    return (cohesion / (soil_depth * soil_dens * 9.81)) + hydro_cons * (math.cos(Slope) * math.tan(frict_ang)) / math.sin(Slope)
```

This is what the model looks like:

[image: Model]

Answer (score 1):

In your expression field you use *!Slope!* as argument.
In your python function you use *Coweeta_slope* as argumnet.
In your return statement you use *Slope* as variable. So the argument name and variable name are not the same. Try:

```
def factorofsafety(...,Slope):
    ...math.sin(Slope)
```

Comment: In addition, according to [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/), the parameters should be lowercase, so `slope`, not `Slope`.